# Returning a function which only allows named arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I use a python3 script to interpolate some measurement data. For this, I want to write a function, which returns the interpolating function. This interpolating function should only take a certain named argument. Here is a simplified version of what I have come up with so far:

```
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

    x = [1, 2]
    y = [1, 3]

    def linear_interp(x, y):
        # Interpolate the data
        y_interp = interp1d(x, y)

        # Create a function taking only a named argument x
        def y_interp_named(*, x):
            return y_interp(x)

        return y_interp_named

    y_linear_interp = linear_interp(x, y)

    print(y_linear_interp(x = 1.5)) # This should work
    print(y_linear_interp(1.5))     # This should throw an error
```

While this works as intended, I wonder if it can be implemented in a more elegant/compact way without the usage of the function `y_interp_named`.

In general: For a function returning another function, is there a way to specify that the returned function should only take certain named arguments other than in the definition of the returned function?

Comment: No, changing the signature requires a layer of indirection, simply because you can't use the original function. So even while you can do it more elegantly it's not possible without an extra function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's [decorators](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) to do something like this.

```
def named_decorater(func):
    def func_named(*, x):
        return func(x)
    return func_named

@named_decorater
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo(2)   #error
foo(x=2) #works
```

Edit: You can also use the decorator like this:

```
named_foo = named_decorator(foo)
named_foo(2)   #error
named_foo(x=2) #works
```

Comment: In context of the question and its use case, I would think the more likely use would be `return named_decorator(y_interp)` with maybe a different function name.

Comment: I would think so

Answer (score 0):

I like @FlashTek's answer, but lambda could be another option.

```
return lambda *, x: y_interp(x)
```

Also, if you're going to use this in more place than one, you could create a decorator that makes all parameters of a function keyword-only. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about this and, as is, it gets rid of any default parameter values in a decorated function.

```
import types

def kwonly(func):
    code = types.CodeType(
        0, # new co_argcount
        func.__code__.co_argcount + func.__code__.co_kwonlyargcount, # new co_kwonlyargcount
        func.__code__.co_nlocals,
        func.__code__.co_stacksize,
        func.__code__.co_flags,
        func.__code__.co_code,
        func.__code__.co_consts,
        func.__code__.co_names,
        func.__code__.co_varnames,
        func.__code__.co_filename,
        func.__code__.co_name,
        func.__code__.co_firstlineno,
        func.__code__.co_lnotab,
        func.__code__.co_freevars,
        func.__code__.co_cellvars
    )
    return types.FunctionType(code, func.__globals__, func.__name__)
```

However, in your case, it can be used as

```
return kwonly(y_interp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> specify that ... function should only take certain named arguments

I searched around for "enforce argspec", "enforce call spec", "obfuscate argspec", and other variants but no luck.

Something similar can be done with a class: You can judge Elegance/compactness.

This is Python 2.7 code, I think 3.6 has subtle differences, I will update for 3.6 when I can.

```
from scipy import interpolate
class F(object):
    '''Given X values, iterpolate Y values.'''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.interp = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
    def __call__(self, **kw):
        try:
            arg = kw['x']
            return self.interp(arg)
        except KeyError as e:
            #something appropriate here
            raise TypeError('x only', e)
```

Usage

```
>>> f = F([1,2],[1,3])
>>> f(x = [1.1,1.11,1.22])
array([ 1.2 ,  1.22,  1.44])

>>> f(y = [1.1,1.11,1.22])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    f(y = [1.1,1.11,1.22])
  File "P:\pyProjects\tmp.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise TypeError('x only', e)
TypeError: ('x only', KeyError('x',))
>>>

>>> f([1.1,1.11,1.22])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    f([1.1,1.11,1.22])
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

---

Another option would be to define a class attribute of acceptable keywords then test for membership:

```
class F(object):
    acceptable = {'x','a'}
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.interp = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
    def __call__(self, **kw):
        if not self.acceptable.issuperset(kw):
            #something appropriate here
            difference = set(kw).difference(self.acceptable)
            raise TypeError('invalid keyword argument',
                            str((list(difference))))
        arg = kw['x']
        return self.interp(arg)
```